# What does "full first-order logic" mean?

Tags: topos-theory, categorical-logic

I see this phrase in the categorical logic literature, but always undefined. What does the "full" mean in "full first-order logic"?

Comment: Full, as opposed to a fragment thereof, e.g. coherent logic, regular logic, cartesian logic...

Comment: @ZhenLin So the usual classical first-order logic? Nothing infinitary?

Comment: I think "classical" would be qualified and intuitionistic is the default. Infinitary would also be qualified. But I suppose it depends on the author's conventions.